# How to Send an array as param in url?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "/mcd/demo.jssp?array="+arr, false ).
```

And how to fetch it in jssp?
My arr lookes like `arr= [3214,2345,84834,4847,83474,3244,234834,........ 30k+ values]`

Comment: send it as post request

Comment: If you are sending `30k+` values then _you are doing something wrong_...

Comment: I can't find any other way to pass data from one page to another. Can you suggest some better ways?

Answer (score 1):

max-length of a URL is [2000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), so you can't send 30 thousand array items as a GET request

Send the request as of type post

```
xhttp.open("POST", "/mcd/demo.jssp", true);
xhttp.send("array="+arr);
```